# How to trigger Jenkins test jobs when code is pushed to git development server using jenkins pipelines?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins test jobs are running on "test.git" repository and development builds are generating on "devtest.git" repository.

Currently I am triggering Jenkins test jobs by scheduling every nightly once and it's pulling the 'lastSuccessfull" build and executing the job properly.

Using Jenkins pipeline i am downloading "lastSuccessfull" build like i mentioned below:

```
wget "https://testting.com/job/UGC/job/%BUILDJOB%/%BUILDNUMBER%/artifact/Source/application_name/bin/release/app.exe/ --no-check-certificate --http-user=%DEV_USERNAME% --http-password=%DEV_PASSWORD% --auth-no-challenge --no-verbose -O app.exe
```

What i need to do is now, when developer pushes code to "devtest.git" repository, build will be get generated and once new build is generated i need to execute the jenkins test jobs immediately.

How do i achieve this? Please help

Answer (score 0):

In the job that runs the build, you can add a step after the build completes to trigger another Jenkins job using the `build` step functionality e.g

```
build job: jobName
```

More info here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#build-build-a-job